# Angular Reactive form validation and data formation issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Trying to add validation at least to select minimum **one** item from `mat-select multipe option`. Currently showing error message on page load until user selects one item from select option, which is working fine.

**expectation:**
When i select all or single select, error message should disappear. (expected and working fine).

**But what happening:**
Required error message is not showing when i deselect the selected single item.

Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

skillForm.component.ts

```
skillList = [
    { skillId: '0', skillName: 'JS' },
    { skillId: '1', skillName: 'TS' },
    { skillId: '2', skillName: 'JAVA' },
    { skillId: '3', skillName: '.Net' },
];

@ViewChild('pickAllCourse') private pickAllCourse: MatOption;
trainerForm = FormGroup;

constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

this.trainerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedSkills :['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]
})

pickAll(): void {
    if(this.pickAllCourse.selected) {
    this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([...this.skillList.map((item) => item.deviceId), 0]);
    } else {
        this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([]);
    }
}


selectOneItem(all): any {
    if (this.pickAllCourse.selected) {
        this.pickAllCourse.deselect();
        return false;
    }
    if (this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.value.length === this.skillList.length) {
        this.pickAllCourse.select();
    }
}

onSubmit(): void{
    console.log('form value', this.trainerForm.value)
    
    // 
}
```

skillForm.component.html

```
    <mat-form-field class="selectedSkills">
        <mat-select multiple ngDefaultControl formControlName="selectedSkills"
            placeholder="Select Device Type">
            <mat-option #pickAllCourse (click)="pickAll()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
            
        <mat-option *ngFor="let i of skillList" [value]="i.deviceId"
            (click)="selectOneItem(pickAllCourse.viewValue)">{{ i.skillName }}
        </mat-option>
        
        </mat-select>
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="trainerForm.controls['selectedSkills '].invalid ">This field is required</span>
    </mat-form-field>
```

**Additionally,** i need help on how to construct the object like below when submit the form for backend.

```
skillList: [
    {skillId: '0'},
    {skillId: '1'}
];
```

when i do console.log the `this.trainerForm.value`, I'm seeing `skillList: ['0']`

Comment: Could you please share your error message?

Comment: Yes. Already updated my SO, @Batajus you can span underneath of  `mat-select`

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but something I saw.  When  you initialized your form in the TS file, this `selectedSkills =['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]` should probably be `selectedSkills: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]` with a `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: @JasonWhite that's not issue. actually it my typo. see updated so. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue(s) & Concern(s)

**Issue 1:**

There is typo error for extra spacing on `trainerForm.controls['selectedSkills ']`.

```
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="trainerForm.controls['selectedSkills '].invalid ">This field is required</span>
```

**Issue 2:**

If the form control(s) requires multiple `Validators`, you should **group them with an Array**.

```js
this.trainerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectedSkills :['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]
})
```

Change to:

```js
this.trainerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  selectedSkills :['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]]
})
```

**Concern 1**

From HTML and Typescript part, the `selectedSkills` will return an array of `number`, but not an array of `Object`. As you use `item.deviceId` (return `string`) and `deviceId` is not exist in `Object` for `skillLists`. I assume that you are using `item.skillId`.

```js
pickAll(): void {
  if(this.pickAllCourse.selected) {
    this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([...this.skillList.map((item) => item.deviceId), 0]);
  } else {
    this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([]);
  }
}
```

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let i of skillList" [value]="i.deviceId"
    (click)="selectOneItem(pickAllCourse.viewValue)">{{ i.skillName }}
</mat-option>
```

Hence, when you `console.log(this.trainerForm.value)`, it will display:

```
{ selectedSkills: [1, 2, 3] }
```

---

### Solution

1. For `<mat-option>` generated with `*ngFor`, set `[value]="{ skillId: i.skillId }"` to return selected value as `object`.
2. Add [`compareWith`](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection) for your `<mat-select>`. Purpose for comparing `this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills` with `[value]="{ skillId: i.skillId }"` to check/uncheck the options when select/deselect All.

```
<mat-form-field class="selectedSkills">
    <mat-select
      multiple
      ngDefaultControl
      formControlName="selectedSkills"
      placeholder="Select Device Type"
      [compareWith]="compareFn"
    >
      <mat-option #pickAllCourse (click)="pickAll()" [value]="0"
        >All</mat-option
      >

      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let i of skillList"
        [value]="{ skillId: i.skillId }"
        (click)="selectOneItem(pickAllCourse.viewValue)"
        >{{ i.skillName }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <span
      class="text-danger"
      *ngIf="trainerForm.controls['selectedSkills'].invalid"
      >This field is required</span
    >
</mat-form-field>
```

3. Set multiple `Validators` in array `[]` as mentioned in **Issue 2**.
4. `pickAll()` to `patchValue` for `this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills` as `{ skillId: item.skillId }` `Object`.
5. `onSubmit()` before pass the form value to API, make sure you filter `skillSets` value with `{ skillId: item.skillId }` `Object` only.
6. `compareFn` is for comparing the selected `skillSets` value with each `<mat-option>` value. Hence, when Select All, all the `<mat-option>` will be selected and vice versa as (2).

```js
trainerForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.trainerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedSkills: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]],
  });
}

pickAll(): void {
  if (this.pickAllCourse.selected) {
    this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([
      ...this.skillList.map((item) => {
        return {
          skillId: item.skillId
        };
      }),
      0,
    ]);
  } else {
    this.trainerForm.controls.selectedSkills.patchValue([]);
  }
}

onSubmit(): void {
  console.log('form value', this.trainerForm.value);

  let postFormValue: any = {
    ...this.trainerForm.value,
    selectedSkills: this.trainerForm.value.selectedSkills.filter(
      (x: any) => typeof x === 'object'
    ),
  };

  console.log(postFormValue);
}

compareFn(obj1: any, obj2: any): boolean {
  return obj1 && obj2 ? obj1.skillId === obj2.skillId : obj1 === obj2;
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-na5elo?file=src/app/skill-form/skill-form.component.ts)

Comment: Thats Awesome. the way you explained the mistake and implementation is so good. this so clean. hence accepting it. Thanks Mate :) @Yong Shun